# Interpolate google maps android roads

Tags: android, google-maps, google-roads-api

I'm doing an Android application that get from server `LatLng` points of a route and write a **polyline snapped** to road.
To get roads points I'm using the [Google API Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)., but in the response I only get the same points that I send in the request.

The request: https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyCcorJdwrFQp5HpR0she_r3PEVOj1TrUTI&path=43.342592253801136%2C-1.7633818398462608%7C43.333786678427664%2C-1.8170163652393967%7C43.31891938155728%2C-1.9850535434670746

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try with nearby points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took me 10min to figure out the issue actually your api is working well but the data you are sending is wrong means to say there is no path available between those points.

check this out https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyCcorJdwrFQp5HpR0she_r3PEVOj1TrUTI&path=43.323579%2C1.960141%7C43.317866%2C1.967716%7C43.318974%2C1.976428

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, but finally I use this library to get the route: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android.git more easy!